# JavaScript change ownership of this

Tags: javascript, oop, this

I have an object, something like so

```
var Egg = function(){

   this.test = $(.slider .label);

    $('.slider').slider({
       min: 1,
       value: 2,
       step: 1,
       value: 10,
       slide: function(){
         this.test.html(ui.value)
       }
    });

}
```

I want to use my variable test inside the slider object. However in its current form `this` refers to the slider and not my egg object, and so trying to use this.test when the slider moves results in undefined.

How can I make `this` refer to my object and not the slider.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this has dynamic scope, so  inside the slide function this is referring to whatever object called that function. this is not equal to what it was equal to when the function is defined (i dont know if im saying that very clearly ... read this http://hoolihan.net/blog-tim/2009/02/17/static-vs-dynamic-scope/). However, you can save this in another variable and access it that way

```
var Egg = function(){

   var self = this;

   this.test = $(.slider .label);

    $('.slider').slider({
       min: 1,
       value: 2,
       step: 1,
       value: 10,
       slide: function(){
         self.test.html(ui.value)
       }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is jQuery? Use `$.proxy`...

```
$('.slider').slider({
   min: 1,
   value: 2,
   step: 1,
   value: 10,
   slide: $.proxy(function(){
     this.test.html(ui.value)
   }, this)
});
```

---

Without jQuery, you could use `Function.prototype.bind`...

```
$('.slider').slider({
   min: 1,
   value: 2,
   step: 1,
   value: 10,
   slide: function(){
     this.test.html(ui.value)
   }.bind(this)
});
```

- [MDN docs & compatibility shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for `Function.prototype.bind`